# Populating array with random numbers/error with user defined function

Tags: c, arrays, random, initialization

My program crashed before anything was executed, except for the `printf()` statements of course. I'm also trying to include a user define function but I'm doing something wrong because it gave me the error that it was undefined, I had it above `int main()` but it still flagged the same error. I need random numbers to populate the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR SIZE    25
#define MAXIMUM     100
#define MINIMUM     60

int main ()
{
int temp_sum;               //Initializes sum of all temperatures in order to calculate average total.
int temp_min, temp_max;     //Initializes minimum and maximum temperature variables.
int hour_count;             //Initializes actual hour of the day.
int temperature[25];        //Initializes array to have 25 elements.
int x, maximum, minimum;
float temp_avg;             //Sets variable to accept a decimal.

hour_count=0;

printf("Temperature Conditions on October 9th, 2015:\n");
printf("Time of Day \t \t Temperature in Degree Farenheit\n");

//Starts for loop to add one to each hour of the day.
for (hour_count=0; hour_count<=24; hour_count++)
    {

    if (temperature[x]>maximum)
        {
            temp_max=temperature[x];
            temp_max=x;
        }
    if (temperature[x]<minimum)
        {
            temp_min=temperature[x];
            temp_min=x;
        }

    printf("%d \t\t\t %d\n", hour_count, temperature);
    }

temp_sum=0;

for (x=0; x<=24; x++)
        {
            temp_sum=temp_sum+temperature[x];
        }
 temp_avg=temp_sum/25;


void GetValue(int value[], int x)
{

value[x] = (rand()%(100-60+1))+60;
}

printf("The maximum temperature for the day is %d degrees Farenheit.\n", temp_max);
printf("The minimum temperature for the day is %d degrees Farenheit.\n", temp_min);
printf("The average temperature for the day is %d degrees   Farenheit.\n", temp_avg);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your final `ptintf`: what temperature do you want to print?

Comment: PLEASE do not change the question once you get the answer. You can always [edit] to ___add___ more details. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your code, all the variables used in the statement

```
  if (temperature[x]>maximum)
```

`x`, `temperature[x]` and `maximum` are uninitialized.

Being unitialized automatic local variables, their initial values are indeterminate. Any attempt to use the values will invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `maximum` too, I didn't notice. I was searching for an invalid array access.

Comment: @iharob yes, but it fisrt hits UB because of `x`.

Comment: @sourav, I see...x is the bad thing, not the uninitialized array...thx.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The uninitialized array and `maximum` would also be a problem.

Comment: @iharob, the program will behave undeterminate but those not being initialized should not let the program crash. They are problems for sure, though. So `x` uninitialized was the cause of the crash.

Comment: Yes some crazy programmers even used this as a source of randomness, OpenSSL does that. It's true that strictly speaking nothing bad should happen. But it's still bad practice to leave the array uninitialized.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I don;t understand. If un-init `x` is a problem, so is un-init `temperature[x]`, right?

Comment: @iharob Why nothing bad should happen? It's still unitialized, right?

Comment: Ok, I am unsure how to actually initialize the array then. I thought int temperature[25] was the initialization?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes but they do have a value, it's undeterminte but it's a value. OpenSSL really does this on purpose. I am not sure but I think you work on a Windows OS. On any os that can run valgrind (Linux, OS X) it is likely that valgrind will complain about uninitialized bytes used by OpenSSL. There is even a compilation flag to make OpenSSL initialize these bytes `-DPURIFY` I think.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, yes, accessing `temperature[]` with an index that is out of bounds is a problem, or actually THE problem. What I meant was that the within-bounds uninitialized array members can not let the program crash.

Comment: @iharob I'm not talking about OpenSSL, i'm talking in general. See, any indeterminate value usage will lead to UB. Now is some (well, most) cases, we can see the expected behavior through UB, but that does not mean, nothing bad should happen, right? It can, and rather, it should. Hope you're getting my point.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I highly doubt that. `temperature[2]` or `temperature[5]` will still lead to UB, at least, theoritically. See Annex J.2, C11.

Comment: @TaylorJane nope, you got to initialize. use something like `int temperature[25] = {0};` and so on...

Comment: @SouravGhosh Absolutely, relying on the behavior being correct in that case is nonsense. I am not defending OpenSSL programmers at all.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The old picture was taken 10 years ago.

Comment: @iharob I see, you managed to change the photo on linkedin, too. :)

Comment: There are so many sorts of UB that the simple usage of the Holy Grail word "UB" is insufficient. The algorithm behaves UB, the compiler behaves UB (implying the algorithm will behave UB), etc. Here, uninitialized `x` caused access out of bounds with a crash; then the uninitialzed array elements make the algorithm behave UB but cannot let it crash, and then sequence points as `a= ++i - --i` can make the compiler behave UB (and hence the algorithm).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `then the uninitialzed array elements make the algorithm behave UB but cannot let it crash` can you quote something, specially supporting the later part?

Comment: No I cannot quote anything other than my understanding of compilers and the assembler they generally produce, which means it happilly will load `temperature[2]` (a valid memory location but with an undeterminate value). Maybe in future there will be hardware with an :"uninitialized" bit for all memory that will invoke an OS call  to execute a random `jmp'` instruction to unify "UB".

Answer (score 0):

You use `x` before initializing it as an array index in the first loop. I guess you mean

```
if (temperature[hour_count] > maximum)
```

instead of

```
if (temperature[x]>maximum)
```

In your code, since `x` is not initialized when used undefined behavior will occur. In fact, the value of `x` is undeterminate at the moment you attempt to use it.